# Populating List<T> from multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, list, populate

So, basically I need to populate this current list with arrays instead of by hand:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<People> people = new List<People>()
            {
                new People{Name="John",Age=21,Email="john@abc.com"}
                new People{Name="Tom",Age=30,Email="tom@abc.com"}
            };
        }
    }
```

So far I have class People like this:

```
    class People
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

And I would like to use arrays instead, from class People into class MainWindow. Something like:

```
    class People
    {
        public string[] Name =
        {
            "John",
            "Tom",
        };
        public int[] Age =
        {
            "21",
            "30",
        }
        ...
    }
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to pupulate this list using these arrays. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason you're using arrays inside of class People instead of List<string>.  Not a criticism, just curiosity.

Comment: I would just like to keep Name, Age, etc in different arrays and then put them together on that one list. I just didn't know any better. Would it be better to use List<string> inside of class People instead?

Comment: A `People` having multiple `Name` and `Age` does not make sense. The way you're currently doing it is the "correct" way. You can create the `People` from separate arrays of names, ages, and emails with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @user2008147 not for the way you are doing it, no.  I was just curious as to your reasoning

Comment: In my opinion, the correct way would be to have a List<Person> within the People class, but that's just my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int c = people.Name.Count;

Enumerable.Range(0,c).Select(i => new People(){Name = people.Name[i], Age = people.Age[i], ...});
```

You need be sure that all arrays have the same size.

And it would be better if you set your "data" as static.

we can do `int c = Math.Min(people.Name.Count, people.Age.Count, ...);` for a better "symetry"

Comment: In this case, that seems to be one of the best options.

Comment: Given formatting of object initialization and removing redundant `()` - this will be the optimal solution.

Comment: Was able to get it working using your solution, thank you very much polkduran and everyone else who helped out! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One of the `Select` overload has `index` as parameter

```
var names = new[]{ "John", "Tom" };
var ages  = new[]{ 21, 30, };
var mails = new[]{ "mail1", "mail2", };

names.Select((name, index) => 
       new People{
       Name = name, 
       Age = ages[index], 
       Email = mails[index]})
     .Dump();
```

prints:

```
Name Age Email 
John 21  mail1 
Tom  30  mail2
```

Comment: @CédricBignon agree.  By symmetric you mean something like polkduran wrote?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Ok, but one note: he uses `people.Name.Count;` which brings asymmetrical aspect a little bit. Don't get me wrong - I like his solution more than mine, but I think there is no pretty solution in current context

Comment: in this case : `int c = Math.Min(people.Name.Count, people.Age.Count,...);` for a better symetry

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, if this is prepopulating the collection

```
public static class PeopleListFactory
{
   public static IEnumerable<People> Content(int someindicator)
   {
      List<People> result = new List<People>();
      switch (someIndicator)
      {      
        case 0: // fill it in here with and from whatever you like.
        break;
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

Then in your main form
it's just

List people = new List(PeopleListFactory.Content(0));